# How can I edit live JavaScript within Edge (Chromium)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, chromium

I have a web page I am developing that is loaded in my QA environment and want to change a hard coded date to pass an if condition for testing and demonstration purposes.

When I edit the elements on the page it does not impact the JavaScript within any  elements, instead only using what was initially sent from the server. See images below, script in elements gets edited, script in sources remains unchanged after saving.

[image: Edited script in the elements tab]

[image: Unchanged script in the sources tab]

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Overrides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/javascript/overrides) function within Edge's development tools I was able to save the web page locally and override the JavaScript with my local changes upon page load.
[image]